# Customize the UIComponents inside UITableViewCell by taking IBOutlets

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have made a `UITableViewCell` with `xib`, inside it I have made a `UIView` and made `IBoutlet` in my custom `tableViewCell` class. I want to set the border color of that `UIView`.

My code in `tableViewCell.h`:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *circleView;
```

In `tableViewCell.m`:

```
#import "OUSTProfileTableViewCell.h"

@implementation OUSTProfileTableViewCell
//@synthesize circleView = _circleView;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        self.circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 3; // this value vary as per your desire
        self.circleView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        self.circleView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
        self.circleView.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef _Nullable)([UIColor lightGrayColor]);
    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

But it's not working.

Comment: add your code in inside the `awakeFromNib`

Comment: @Anbu.karthik It worked. Thank u :).

Comment: welcome bro....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put code inside

```
 - (void)awakeFromNib {
  [super awakeFromNib];
  // Initialization code

    self.circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 3; // this value vary as per your desire
    self.circleView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.circleView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    self.circleView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;

 }
```